Event Color based on Resource / Room Color - Fullcalendar.js PHP MySQL
I want to display the event color / background color based on each room's color (I have 3 different colors for 3 different rooms/resource). But the parsed colors from resources.php wasn't displayed as I expected in every events on each different rooms (3 rooms). So I want to change the event's colors based on their room's placement (room_id) on MySQL db.
calendar:

resources.php
$sql = "SELECT id, room_name AS title FROM room_list";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$colors = ['#00DCFF', '#fe9e0c', '#179f66'];
$colorIndex = 0;

$resources = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row['color'] = $colors[$colorIndex % count($colors)];
    $resources[] = $row;
    $colorIndex++;
  }
}

echo json_encode($resources);

$stmt->close();

script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "models/resources.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (resources) {
      initializeCalendar(resources);
    },
  });
});

function initializeCalendar(resources) {
  let events = [];
  if (scheds) {
    Object.keys(scheds).map((k) => {
      let row = scheds[k];
      let room = resources.find((resource) => resource.id == row.room_id);
      let color = room.color;
      let event = {
        id: row.id,
        title: row.title,
        start: row.start_datetime,
        end: row.end_datetime,
        resourceId: row.room_id,
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
      };
      
      events.push(event);
    });
  }
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: "CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next,today",
      center: "title",
      right:
        "resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridFourDay,resourceTimeGridMonths",
    },
    views: {
      resourceTimeGridFourDay: {
        type: "resourceTimeGrid",
        duration: { days: 3 },
        buttonText: "3 Days",
      },
      resourceTimeGridMonths: {
        type: "dayGridMonth",
        duration: { months: 1 },
        buttonText: "Months",
      },
      resourceTimeGridDay: {
        buttonText: "Day",
      },
    },
    resources: resources,
    events: events,
    editable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    datesAboveResources: true,
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
      if (scheds) {
        Object.keys(scheds).map((k) => {
          let row = scheds[k];
          let room = resources.find((resource) => resource.id == row.room_id);
          let color = room.color;
          info.el.style.backgroundColor = color;
        });
      }
    },
  });

  calendar.render();
}

I tried every possible way on script.js to change the backgroundColor or textColor to display the same color based on each rooms in my script.js in view types - even using eventDidMount like the shown image.
Now it just displays the green color (#179f66) for every event.
I tried to change the eventDidMount to this:
eventDidMount: function (info) {
      if (scheds) {
        Object.keys(scheds).map((k) => {
          let row = scheds[k];
          let room = resources.find((resource) => resource.id == row.room_id);
          let color = room.color;
          info.event.extendedProps.backgroundColor = color;
        });
      }
    },

but it only changes the dots color:


Please check whether this is a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem

As per the eventDisplay documentation, by default you will only see the dots on timed events in the dayGrid view, not the coloured rectangle.
If you want to see that coloured rectangle in the dayGrid view, you can simply change the eventDisplay setting to block, as follows:
eventDisplay: "block"

Then you don't need any of your eventDidMount code.
Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjqgWWw

Oh my god, I think I didn't read the documentation enouugh that I missed this property method, thank you for the answer, it worked as expected
